# Python isnt printing my regex expression results (or anything)?

Tags: python, regex, file, printing

I'm trying to extract the first number that appears in the first line of my text file. I'm a noob, so I'm playing around with regex. The issue I have is nothing is printing, so i'm not sure if it's my code or something else?

I've tried printing my file names too and nothing happens either so i'm not sure whats going on

```
work_dir = "User/...my folder of 9 text files"
for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(work_dir, "*.txt")):
    with io.open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        first_line = file.readline()
        for line[34:] in first_line:
            if "LOCUS" in line[0:34]:
                matches = int(re.search(r"(\d+)", first_line).group(0))
                print(matches)

    name = os.path.basename(path).replace(".gbff", "")
    print(name)
```

Here's the head of an example of the types of files im working with.
It's a text file even though it looks like a table here.

```
LOCUS       AE017334             *5227419* bp    DNA     circular BCT 03-DEC-2015
DEFINITION  Bacillus anthracis str. 'Ames Ancestor', complete genome.
ACCESSION   AE017334
VERSION     AE017334.2
DBLINK      BioProject: PRJNA10784
            BioSample: SAMN02603433
```

I need the number I've put ** around

Comment: Aa minimal sample of files with content would help

Comment: I've pasted an excerpt :) @kamal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually got output for your regex and text format, and its working fine with slicing and other stuff u mentioned, so its not the regex or the for loop part, since u are saying its not printing anything and i am assuming its not printing out errors too i think it has something to do with your path or directory readings.

anyways here's your regex part:
f

```
first_line='LOCUS       AE017334             *5227419* bp    DNA     circular BCT 03-DEC-2015'
matches = int(re.search(r"(\d+)", first_line[34:]).group(0))
print(matches)
```

output:

```
5227419
```

posting this so others trying to answer can skip these steps and check into the other parts of your code

Comment: Thank you, this works really well. It does seem like the issue is in my path somewhere but I'm not sure why. I'lll leave this open for a bit in case someone can spot something I can't see

Answer (score 1):

```
str = open('a.txt', 'r').read()
import re
start = '*'
end = '*'

print( (str[str.find(start)+len(start):str.rfind(end)]))
print("\n")
```

I saved your file as a.txt replace with your file name & if you need only locus values. Re arrange text before using regx
[image]

Comment: I tried to run this but nothing is printing for some reason :( thank you, I'll come back to this when I have it fixed

Comment: See output image. I've just updated. Check text file path again

Comment: I think it's an issue on my end. Thanks for posting the output! How would I get only the second number out? Maybe with split?

Comment: See i've modified code. Pls upvote & accept as valid answer

Comment: This works when I run it with a variable and when I add split, thanks! Seems the printing thing is my issue so I'll leave the question open in case someone can spot why